# Unable to detach PCI device from running virtual machine ("Device is already in the process of unplug")

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, pci, virsh

I'm forwarding a host USB hub using this virsh config:

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
  <source>
    <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x13' slot='0x00' function='0x3'/>
  </source>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
```

This works perfectly. However, I want to be able to hot attach/detach this USB hub from the VM at any time. In theory this should work:

```
$ virsh detach-device my-vm-name pci-root-usb-hub.xml
Device detached successfully
```

Ok, looks promising, however the PCI device hasn't actually been detached. I can still see my webcam and move my mouse around inside the VM. If I run the command again:

```
$ virsh detach-device my-vm-name pci-root-usb-hub.xml
error: Failed to detach device from pci-root-usb-hub.xml
error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'device_del': Device hostdev2 is already in the process of unplug
```

And it seems to be frozen there. I'm unable to actually detach the PCI device from the VM without shutting the VM down.

I'm unable to find any errors in `libvirtd.log` or `qemu/my-vm-name.log`. Is there an obvious reason why this is not working?

---

- Host OS: Arch Linux (kernel 5.13.12)
- Guest OS: Windows 10

Comment: What happens when you reboot everything and remove the device from virt-manager?

Comment: @harrymc Can you elaborate? Do you mean if I connect the device *after* launching the VM? That does work, but I still can't disconnect it.

Comment: I was just wondering if virt-manager did more than just `virsh detach-device`.

Comment: Have you advanced with the problem?

Comment: @harrymc I have made no progress

Comment: Then have you tried and is it the same with virt-manager?

Comment: @harrymc I just now understood what you meant. I will try later today.

Answer (score 0):

Following a trail from these:
https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/gib29u/comment/fqdlo6a/
https://github.com/olavmrk/usb-libvirt-hotplug

..i was able to boil the xml (which can be all on one line) down to this:

```
virsh detach-device 28 /dev/stdin <<DL
<hostdev type="usb"><source><vendor id="0x1050"/><product id="0x0407"/></source></hostdev>
DL
```

..detach will also accept just the bus and device number:

```
virsh detach-device 28 /dev/stdin <<DL
<hostdev type="usb"><source><address bus="3" device="26"/></source></hostdev>
DL
```

..which can be onelined with a Heredoc:
`eval $'virsh detach-device 28 /dev/stdin << DL \n<hostdev type="usb"><source><vendor id="0x1050"/><product id="0x0407"/></source></hostdev>\nDL'`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465068/346155 (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370098/single-line-heredocument-possible-in-bash)

If you have 2 devices from the same vendor, for example 2 Yubikeys, using the same vendor/product twice will detach both. But the bus/device must be used to add them. Of course, the bus/device must be used to attach if there are multiple same devices. Unfortunately, those added though the "Redirect USB Devices" in the viewer menu can't be removed this way afaik.

(just replace detach with attach for that) (`usbreset 1050:0407` also wont remove them.)

Comment: Hotplugging USB devices worked, but forwarding USB devices in general was very unstable for me. Only forwarding the whole USB hub as a PCI device worked perfectly.